# Write BLE gatt characteristic on Android — error status 255

Tags: android-ble, rxandroidble

Experimenting with sample kotlin program, trying to read/write BLE device with channels from 0-7

When reading it gives me value like this: (0x06)

```
onCharacteristicRead(), status=0, value=[uuid='ba7e7814-5b67-43d3-bd80-e72cc83ae801', hexValue=[06]]
```

but when trying to write same output it gives me, it gives me error GATT 255, out of range:

```
CharacteristicWriteOperation{MAC='00:A0:50:E8:78:86', characteristic=[uuid='ba7e7814-5b67-43d3-bd80-e72cc83ae801', hexValue=[30, 36]]}

onCharacteristicWrite(), status=255, value=[uuid='ba7e7814-5b67-43d3-bd80-e72cc83ae801']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you read: `[0x06]`

```
onCharacteristicRead(), status=0, value=[uuid='ba7e7814-5b67-43d3-bd80-e72cc83ae801', hexValue=[06]]
```

What you wrote: `[0x30, 0x36]` (which may correspond to String "06" as ASCII hex value for `'0'` is `0x30` and for `'6'` is `0x36`)

```
CharacteristicWriteOperation{MAC='00:A0:50:E8:78:86', characteristic=[uuid='ba7e7814-5b67-43d3-bd80-e72cc83ae801', hexValue=[30, 36]]}
```

You probably want to write back hexadecimal value `0x06`, not the string `"06"`

[Status 255 is `GATT_OUT_OF_RANGE` which means that the written value is outside of range accepted by your peripheral](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/android-7.1.1_r44/stack/include/gatt_api.h#70).